# How can I skip after_create callbacks in my Rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a `SaleQualifier` model which `has_many Answers`. I'm trying to set up a basic Rspec test to ensure that the `Answer` always has reference to its parent `SaleQualifier` using the following:

```
  it 'is invalid without a sale_qualifier' do
   answer.sale_qualifier_id = nil
   expect(answer).to_not be_valid
 end
```

My `Answer` model has an `after_save` callback to lookup the `answer_type` via the `SaleQualifier` and its associated `Question`. It looks like this:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :answer_text, presence: true
 belongs_to :sale_qualifier
 validates :sale_qualifier_id, presence: true
 validate :check_answer_text_type
 after_save :update_sale_qualifier

 TYPE_REGEX = {
    'Integer' => /^[-+]?\d+$/,
    'Boolean' => /^(true|false)$/
 }

 def check_answer_text_type
    question = Question.find_by_id(self.sale_qualifier.question_id)
    answer_type = question.answer_type
    if answer_type == 'Datetime'
        if !answer_text.is_a?(Date)
            self.errors.add(:answer_type, 'must be a valid date')
        end
    elsif answer_type == 'Integer' || answer_type == 'Boolean'  
        unless answer_text.match(TYPE_REGEX[answer_type])
            self.errors.add(:answer_type, 'invalid format')
        end
    else
        return true
    end
 end

 def update_sale_qualifier
    sale_qualifier.update_next_question
    sale_qualifier.save
 end
end
```

As you can see, the Answer model finds its question via the SaleQualifier model using `question = Question.find_by_id(self.sale_qualifier.question_id)` - when I add in the code `validates :sale_qualifier_id, presence: true` to my Answer model this works (the answer is no longer valid) but it also breaks the `check_answer_text_type` method because the call to `self` is no longer valid.

This results in a `NoMethodError for nil:NilClass` which is to be expected.

Is there a way I can skip the `after_save` validation in this case? That is tested in other parts of the code anyway, all I'm trying to achieve here is to prove that an Answer won't be allowed to float around my database without being associated with a SaleQualifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way would be to stub `update_sale_qualifier`, so you will check that it is indeed called, but the code won't be executed so your test should be fine:

```
expect(answer).to receive(:update_sale_qualifier)
```

You can check [RSpec doc on this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs).

Comment: Thanks Taglia, I got it working using   `it 'is invalid without a sale_qualifier' do
   expect(answer).to receive(:update_sale_qualifier).with(sale_qualifier_2)
   answer.update_sale_qualifier(sale_qualifier_2)
  end`